# IE is throwing an error at this section of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This code is throwing the following error in IE, but not in any other browser:

```
'undefined' is null or not an object
```

Does anyone know why? I can't find what's wrong with the code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery("ul.sf-menu").supersubs({
            minWidth: 12,
            maxWidth: 27,
            extraWidth: 1,
        }).superfish({
            delay: 100,
            animation: { opacity: 'show' },
            speed: 'fast'
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Load the page into IE, then press F12.  You will get the developer tools.  On the top of the screen, click "Script" and "start Debugging".  Then return to the page, and press F5 to refresh the page.  If it throws an exception in `$(document).ready()`, you will see the exception in the debugging session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the extra comma after `extraWidth: 1`.

Note: I do not have IE on this computer so I can't test this, but your syntax is completely correct otherwise. My guess is that IE sees the extra comma, fails, and passes `undefined` to `supersubs` instead.

Comment: Hmm... that seems to have fixed the issue. Why would IE choke at a comma?

Comment: Commas are supposed to have something after them.

Comment: Oh, and I would accept your answer, but I need to wait ~10 minutes.

Comment: When it sees the comma, it thinks something else must be coming after it.

Comment: @Richard J.Ross III, usually I would agree with you about this statement, but in this rare case I would confidently say that IE was right.. and had this been in any compiled programming language, a compiler would (and rightfully so) choked on the extra comma.

Comment: good cath @Reid, I looked through it focused on the brackets and parenthesis... didnt notice the comma though!

Comment: @mc10: It is fairly irritating, I agree, since most high-level [scripting] languages do allow an extra comma (and all of the other browsers in the case of JavaScript). But it's just one of the quirks of IE.

Comment: @Center: C# allows trailing commas in object initializers.

Comment: @Slaks, I did not know that. Most of my programming is in AS3 (if you consider that programming, since it is compiled to run on the flash vm), C, C++, and Java. I have done some C# but only very little. So based from my experience most all of them languages (even AS3) choke with trailing commas. Good to know though, either way it is a compiler/interpreter preference and would prob be best to follow traditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra comma after the "extraWidth: 1"

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery("ul.sf-menu").supersubs({
            minWidth: 12,
            maxWidth: 27,
            extraWidth: 1
        }).superfish({
            delay: 100,
            animation: { opacity: 'show' },
            speed: 'fast'
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780617/ie8-and-jquery-null-pointers) from a previous post, it may be due to the jQuery trying to modify or create a value that has not been explicitly declared in your css. Try setting width values for ul with class sf-menu.